# Pickaday - day select and restrict

Tags: pikaday

I am a relative newbie to JQuery, so please go easy on me ;)

I have a booking form that needs to have two selectsion options:

Number of days of stay (dropdown)
Start Date (date picker)

When a certain number of days have been selected, some of the days on the date picker need to be hidden.

Options
3 days - Can book on Friday only
4 days - Can book on Monday only
7 days - Can book on Saturday only

I nearly managed to do this with pikaday, but ran into a 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.' issue as my JQuery was continually calling on the same picker.

Here is the code that I used:

```js
function next_day() {
            var index;
            var day_nums = document.getElementById("day_nums");
            var options = day_nums.getElementsByTagName("option")
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selected) {
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            index = index + 1;
            if (index >= day_nums.length) {
                alert('For a flexible booking, please call: ##########')
            }
            else {               
                day_nums.value = day_nums[index].value;
            }
 
        }
        function prev_day() {
            var index;
            var day_nums = document.getElementById("day_nums");
            var options = day_nums.getElementsByTagName("option")
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selected) {
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            index = index - 1;
 
            if (index <= -1) {
                // Alert('First record reached')
            }
            else {               
                day_nums.value = day_nums[index].value;
            }
        }    




/*PIKADAY*/
function get_days(currnum)
{
 if(currnum > 0) { $('#date_div').show(); }
 else { $('#date_div').hide(); }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

 
  $(".button, #day_nums").on("click", function() {
    var zValue = $('#day_nums').val();
   get_days(zValue);
   update_date(zValue);
  // $("#cal_picker").val("");
  });
 
 
 function update_date(day_num)
 {
    var picker = new Pikaday({
  bound:false,
    disableDayFn: function(date){
       
  if(day_num == 3) { // FRIDAY
  return date.getDay() === 1 
   || date.getDay() === 2 
   || date.getDay() === 3 
   || date.getDay() === 4
   
   || date.getDay() === 6 
   || date.getDay() === 7
   || date.getDay() === 0;
  }
       
  if(day_num == 4) { // MONDAY
  return date.getDay() === 2 
   || date.getDay() === 3 
   || date.getDay() === 4  
   || date.getDay() === 5
   || date.getDay() === 6
   || date.getDay() === 7
   || date.getDay() === 0;
  }
       
  if(day_num >= 7) { // SATURDAY
  return date.getDay() === 1 
   || date.getDay() === 2
   || date.getDay() === 3 
   || date.getDay() === 4  
   || date.getDay() === 5
   || date.getDay() === 7
   || date.getDay() === 0;
  }
    },
    field: document.getElementById('cal_picker')
 });
 }

 
});
```

```css
.num_nights, #date_div {display: none;}
#num_nights_off {display: block;}
.inc_day, .dec_day { 
 background:#047fcb;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    display: initial;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/pikaday.js"></script>

<div id="day_picker">Nights:

 <select name="day_nums" id="day_nums">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
 
 <input type="button" class="button" value="-" onclick="prev_day();"/>&nbsp;<input type="button" class="button" value="+" onclick="next_day();" />
 
</div>


<div id="date_div">Dates: <input id="cal_picker" name="curr_date" value=""></div>
```